# Why is a circular aperture defined by the circle function rather than a heaviside step function?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, diffraction

In the chapter 4 of the text "Introduction To Fourier Optics" by Goodman, the diffraction pattern of light passing through a circular aperture was studied. The diffraction pattern on the image plane $(x_i, y_i)$, is given by the fourier transform of the amplitude transmittance $U(x_o,y_o)$ on the aperture plane $(x_o, y_o)$ with relevant phases; through the Fraunhofer approximation. I.e.,

$$U(x_i,y_i) = \frac{\exp[ikz] \exp[ik(x_i^2 + y_i^2)/2z]}{i\lambda z}\mathcal{F}\left[U(x_o,y_o)\right]\, .$$

For a circular aperture of diameter $l$, the author uses the amplitude transmittance, $U(x_o,y_o)=circ\left(\frac{r}{l/2}\right)$. Where $r=\sqrt{x_o^2+y_o^2}$, and,

$$  
circ(r) =
  \begin{cases}
    1, & \text{for } r < 1 \\
    1/2, & \text{for } r = 1 \\
    0, & \text{for }r > 1 \, .
  \end{cases}
$$

My question is, what is the reason for the $1/2$ when $r=1$? Are we not able to use a heaviside step function in the radial coordinate to encapsulate the amplitude transmittance? I.e. $U(x_o,y_o) = H(r-l/2)$, where,

$$
H(r-r_0) =
  \begin{cases}
    1, & \text{for } r \leq r_0 \\
    0, & \text{for } r > r_0 \,.
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function that satisfies the so-called Dirichlet condition, that is one that has finite number of discontinuities and finite number of monotonic pieces (more generally has finite variation), see [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions), will have its Fourier series or transform take the mid-point value at the points of discontinuities, so it is convenient to assume that value from the beginning since it makes no difference in the end.